Properties for a metric space to have best approximation element
A metric space $E$ has the property that, for any closed subset A in E and for any point $x$ in $E$, there exists a point $y$ in $A$ such that $d(x,y)=d(x,A)$. Can we conclude that every bounded sequence in $E$ has a convergent subsequence?

Are you assuming that every $A$ satisfies this property? That the distance from any point $x$ to $A$ is attained? It is unclear what you are asking about.

I have edited my question, I hope it is more clear now.

We can’t conclude that every bounded sequence has a convergent sequence. In $(N,d)$, we define $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$, and $d(x,y)=1$ in other cases.
If we take the sequence $a_i=i$, it’s bounded but it doesn’t have a convergent subsequence. We can verify that every closed subset in N has a best approximation element.
